# Using defined names in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I previously set up the conditional formatting so it would prevent duplicates but have realised that certain text in the cells will have to be there so I don't want it flagging up.

I have created a list of names and defined them as "Names", the cells should only flag up if the same names are in multiple cells. Is there a way of doing this?

If this doesn't make sense here is an example.

Defined Name = Name

Jack

```
Cell 1  Cell 2
ABC     ABC
```

I don't want this to show up as a duplicate.

```
Cell 1 Cell 2
ABC    ABC
Jack   Jack
```

This should flag up as a duplicate as the text "Jack" is in my defined list.

[image: These cells shouldn't show red]

[image: The cells should only go red when the same persons name is allocated on the same day but in a different area]

In the first picture the cells shouldn't go red

The cells should only go red when the same persons name is allocated on the same day but in a different area (see picture 2)

Comment: Its based on a time table so on certain days it may say something such as Clinic Day and this will be in multiple cells, so I don't want this flagging up. I just want it to flag up if the same person is assigned to it, so a duplicate name.

Comment: I've added some pictures, hopefully this will make sense

Answer (score 0):

If you define the range of the cells you want to format as "Range" and the range starts from (say) A1, the conditional formatting formula you want should be:-

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,Names,0)),COUNTIF(Range,A1)>1)
```

applied to all cells in Range.

You could try something like this to exclude matches in the same day:-

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Names,0))*
(INT((COLUMN(A2)+ISODD(MIN(COLUMN(Range2))))/2)<>INT((COLUMN(Range2)+ISODD(MIN(COLUMN(Range2))))/2))*
(A2=$A2:$D2))
```

Comment: Would this work with the example I've placed above? It needs to be set for specific cells.

Comment: Yes if both cells contained Justin and he was on your list, but not as shown because "Cleanup - Justin" wouldn't match "Justin"

Comment: I will try this but I'm not entirely sure how to set it up as I need it to apply to AM only and then another to PM only as that member of staff could work on the same area in the morning and the afternoon. So I would have to select the exact cells that need to be placed in the formual

Comment: Yes if you have several areas and only want to count matches outside the current area it will change the question somewhat and may need a different approach.

Comment: I see, not as easy as I was hoping then. Thank you

Comment: I will put in a formula to exclude matches in pairs but it does get more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for this, I still don't understand so I have just given up.

Comment: OK. I think the point is that a small difference in the layout can have a big effect on how difficult the question is so would have needed more sample data e.g. I think you might want to match 'Cleanup - Justin' with 'Washup - Justin' in a different area and that is quite hard unless there is a clear pattern like the name always appears after ' - '.